# JavaScript Running In Frame Does Not Load

Tags: iframe

I have an iFrame at subdomain.somedomain.com and it is displayed on somedomain.com.  I have control over both domains if changes need to be made on either side.

In the frame I load a form that exists on subdomain.somedomain.com. When the user types in the form there is a character counter to show how many characters have been typed. It functions by appending itself to the parent element based on a set of CSS IDs.  This used to work, but I do not know when it stopped working.

I get "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://subdomain.somedomain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

I do not understand how this is cross-domain as both the site loaded into the frame and the script it is calling are both on https://subdomain.somedomain.com.

If someone can please help understand what needs to happen for a script to run on the page loaded in a frame I would appreciate it.

I am not sure it makes a difference but this is all happening on Drupal.  I have changed the X-Frame options so that the page can be loaded in the frame at all.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I `parent.scrollTo(0,0);` in my code which is a clear violation of cross-origin policy. I think this out and it works like a charm.